# Stock Strategy(Buy and Hold) - Are there any logic errors in my code?

Tags: r, logic

I am a freshman in this field and I want to use R language to test my simple strategy.  My strategy is, first, I get the average price through the histroy prices of last 4 years, then I buy the stock when price lower than average price and hold it.  Now, I continue to buy until the current price higher than average price then I sell them(my code is more comlpex on my sell condition). And the strategy would be a cycle along with the time.

Ex:Buy...Buy...Buy...Sell*3...Buy...Sell*1........(until now)

So the question here is: Are there any  logic errors in the code? Does while and if functions put on the right place?

```
## 980days = 4years(Working Days)
setwd("C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Learn/R/XX/TW50")
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
STK <- as.xts(read.zoo("2409.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ',' ))
closeprice <- Cl(STK)
st <- mean( closeprice[nrow(STK)-979]:closeprice[nrow(STK)])
STK <- as.matrix(STK)

##profit
PL <- setNames(rep(0, 980), rownames(STK)[(nrow(STK)-979):nrow(STK)]) 
long <- 0 ##Buy
n <- 0 ##Stock Quantity

m = nrow(STK)-979
while (m < nrow(STK)){
##Buy(accumulate)    
if(Cl(STK)[m] <= (st*0.97)){
        long = long + as.numeric(Cl(STK)[m])
        n = n+1}
##Sell(All)
while(Cl(STK)[m] >= (st*1.03) && (Cl(STK)[m]-Cl(STK)[(m-1)]) < 0 
      && Cl(STK)[(m-1)] > Cl(STK)[(m-2):(m-3)] && m < nrow(STK)) {
      PL[m-(nrow(STK)-979)] = as.numeric(Cl(STK)[m])*n - long    
      long = 0; n = 0
      m = m+1
      }
    m = m+1
}    

plot(cumsum(PL), type="l", col="red", lwd=2)
```

Comment: You are asking for a code review, which is really out of scope for SO.  Why don't you write a unit test and validate your code with that?

Comment: Without knowing the format of the data file there isn't too much advice I can give here. The only thing I can see that you should watch out for, is that `m` seems to be being used as a loop counter for the outer loop, and you are incrementing it in your inner loop - which when exiting will skip over rows that you might have wanted to process in the outer one.

Comment: `m` means one day, and thank you for all your assistances. I had change at least three methods, finally got the non-horizontal line！(I deleted `m=m+1` in the inner loop and plus `break` in it.)

Comment: The format is txt and the texts include Date - Open price - High price- Close price - Low price - volumes.